# JavaScript doesn't show on webpage?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Cookie Clicker</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="JS"></div>


<script>
var cookies = 0;

function addCookies(){
    cookies += 1;
    getElementById("JS").innerHTML="Cookies: " + cookies;
}
 getElementById("JS").innerHTML="Cookies: " + cookies;

</script>

<button onclick='addCookies()'>Add Cookies</button>

</body>

</html>
```

The `addCookies()` doesn't work. It is supposed to say in the browser `Cookies:` variable`cookies`. Could someone explain it to me? All it shows in the browser is the button.

Comment: 1. Developer's console. 2. `document.getElementById()`

Comment: Thanks. I see what little mistake I made. sorry for you having to waster your time with this simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `getElementById` function in native javascript. Use `document.getElementById` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use document.getElementById() or $("#your_id") with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cookies as a variable this is a reserved variable.
and check the exact error through developer tool may help more.